# How to copy a value in a vector to next position(s) in vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector that looks something like this:

```
c(0.5,0,0,0,0,0.7,0,0,0,0,0.4,0,0,0,0)
```

Suppose I want to copy the values on positions 1, 6 and 11 (the ones that are not 0) to the four positions following that specific value, to make the vector look like this:

```
c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4)
```

How could I best do that in R?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably loop through every single element greater 0 using `lapply`, then apply `rep` function to repeat each of these values 5 times and merge the resulting list entries via `do.call("c", ...)`.

```
do.call("c", lapply(which(tmp > 0), function(i) rep(tmp[i], 5)))
[1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I'm trying to understand this. Is it correct that you now tell R to repeat the values that are > 0 to the position of that specific value and the next four positions?

Comment: Exactly. You can control the number of repetitions within the `rep` function (set to 5 by now).

Comment: -1 because it requires the user to set the number of repetitions and cannot deal with unequal numbers of zeros.

Comment: @Roland, you're definitely right. My line of code is tailored to this specific example where every element larger than 0 has to be repeated five times. As you see below, there are more flexible solutions than that!

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility:

```
vec <- c(0.5,0,0,0,0,0.7,0,0,0,0,0.4,0,0,0,0)

library(zoo)
vec[vec==0] <- NA
na.locf(vec)
#[1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4
```

Comment: @eddi, just set na.locf(vec,na.rm=T).

Comment: @Thell I assume you mean `na.rm=F`

Comment: Yep... that's what I get for commenting right as dinner is being served.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way:

```
zero.locf <- function(x) {
    if (x[1] == 0) stop('x[1] should not be 0')
    with(rle(x), {
        no.0 <- replace(values, values == 0, values[(values == 0) - 1])
        rep(no.0, lengths)
    })
}
x <- c(0.5,0,0,0,0,0.7,0,0,0,0,0.4,0,0,0,0)
zero.locf(x)
#  [1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4
```

`rle(x)` returns a `list` with items `values` and `lengths`.

```
rle(x)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:6] 1 4 1 4 1 4
  values : num [1:6] 0.5 0 0.7 0 0.4 0
```

`with` opens up this `list` and lets us reference these entries directly.

Comment: this does smth weird when there are 0's in the beginning (not really sure what it does as I didn't read the solution very carefully)

Comment: also I get warnings when running this for: `set.seed(1); v = sample(c(-10:10, rep(0, 10000)), 1e5, T)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's another base R approach. Initial zeros are left as is:

```
v = c(0,1,2,-2.1,0,3,0,0.4,0,0)
v[v!=0] = diff(c(0, v[v!=0]))
cumsum(v)
# [1]  0.0  1.0  2.0 -2.1 -2.1  3.0  3.0  0.4  0.4  0.4
```

And here are some benchmarks:

```
roland = function(v) {v[v == 0] <- NA; na.locf(v)}
mp = function(x) {with(rle(x), rep(replace(values, values==0, values[which(values == 0)-1]), lengths))}
quant = function(dat) {not.0 <- (dat != 0); approx(which(not.0), dat[not.0], xout = seq(along.with = dat), method = "constant", rule = 2)}
eddi = function(v) {v[v!=0] = diff(c(0, v[v!=0])); cumsum(v)}

v = sample(c(-10:10, 0), 1e6, TRUE)
microbenchmark(roland(v), mp(v), quant(v), eddi(v), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# roland(v) 595.1630 625.7692 638.4395 650.4758 664.9224    10
#     mp(v) 410.8224 433.6775 469.9346 496.6328 528.3218    10
#  quant(v) 646.1775 753.0684 759.9805 838.4281 883.3383    10
#   eddi(v) 265.8064 286.2922 316.7022 339.0333 354.0836    10
```

Comment: It'd be interesting to see the benchmarks after scaling up a bit too.

Comment: @Thell how much bigger than 1e6 do you want to go? :)

Comment: Ha! How did I miss that! :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using `approx`

```
dat   <- c(0.5,0,0,0,0,0.7,0,0,0,0,0.4,0,0,0,0)
not.0 <- (dat != 0)
approx(which(not.0), dat[not.0], xout = seq(along.with = dat), method = "constant", yleft = 0, rule = 1:2)
# $x
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
#
# $y
# [1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4
```

And here is an alternative that relies on the stated structure of the initial vector (repetitions of a non-zero value followed by 4 zeros).
It adresses the speed issue but at the cost of flexibility.

```
dat <- c(0.5,0,0,0,0,0.7,0,0,0,0,0.4,0,0,0,0)
rep(dat[seq(1, length(dat), by = 5)], each = 5)
```

Comment: I think this fills in the first element to the left if the vector starts with 0's

Comment: @eddi Yes. I've made relevant changes to leave potential initial zero(s) unchanged.