# Find most recent non-missing value in a vector

Tags: r, vector, missing-data

I'm trying to return the most recent row in the vector with a non-missing value. For instance, given

```
x <- c(1,2,NA,NA,3,NA,4)
```

Then function(x) would output a list like:

```
c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
```

Very simple question, but running it with loops or brute force on multiple columns takes forever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a value in a vector to next position(s) in vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320312/how-to-copy-a-value-in-a-vector-to-next-positions-in-vector)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zoo::na.locf` for that

```
require(zoo)
x <- c(1, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4)
na.locf(x)
## [1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. [Will accept after the 15 minute interval unless a better answer appears.]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `Reduce` function:

```
> x <- c(1,2,NA,NA,3,NA,4)
> locf <- function(x,y) if(is.na(y)) x else y
> Reduce( locf, x, accumulate=TRUE )
[1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

This way you do not need to load an extra package (and it could be customized to different types of objects if needed).

The `Reduce` option is quicker than `zoo::na.locf` for the sample vector on my computer:

```
> library(zoo)
> library(microbenchmark)
> 
> microbenchmark( 
+ Reduce( locf, x, accumulate=TRUE ),
+ na.locf(x)
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                               expr     min       lq  median       uq     max
 Reduce(locf, x, accumulate = TRUE)  22.169  24.0160  27.506  29.3530 112.073
                         na.locf(x) 149.841 151.8945 154.357 169.5465 377.271
 neval
   100
   100
```

Though there may be other situations where `na.locf` will be faster.  I was actually surprised at the amount of difference.

---

Benchmarking on bigger data shows the difference clearly between `na.locf` from `zoo` package and using `Reduce`:

```
x <- sample(c(1:5, NA), 1e6, TRUE)
require(zoo)
require(microbenchmark)
locf <- function(x,y) if(is.na(y)) x else y

microbenchmark(Reduce( locf, x, accumulate=TRUE ), na.locf(x), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
                              expr       min        lq    median       uq      max neval
Reduce(locf, x, accumulate = TRUE) 5480.4796 5958.0905 6605.3547 7458.404 7915.046    10
                        na.locf(x)  661.2886  911.1734  950.2542 1026.348 1095.642    10
```

Comment: GregSnow, you can see the difference on bigger data. I've edited your post with the benchmarking results. In general, I've the opinion that `Reduce` does not scale well.

Comment: @Arun, It would be interesting to see where they switch places and how much that depends on other factors.

Comment: yes definitely. I'll try to see if I can test on some functions (from answers here on SO with Reduce) and write-up here on SO.